# tengo un problema en la salida de mi código

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, condiciones, dev-c++

Mi problema es que a la hora de que en el `printf` me coloque el número de veces que esta en número 3 en el vector, el programa coloca otro número que no es.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
//programa que visualice y ponga en pantalla los numeros

#include<stdio.h>
void leer(int a[]);

int main() {
    
    int vec[10]={3,3,3,3,5,5,9,9,9,9};
    
    leer(vec);
    
    return 0;
}
void leer(int a[]){
    
    int i, j;
    
    j=0;
    
    for(i=0 ; i<10 && i!=3 ; i++){
        if(a[i]=3){
            j =j+1;
        }
    }
    printf("Existen %i elementos del numero 3",j);
}
```

Comment: En tu if estas haciendo una asignacion "=" en vez de una comparación "==".

Comment: me sigue dando el mismo error aun así haya corregido eso. perdón

Comment: Aparte de lo dicho por @nashvent, tu condición en el `for( )` está mal. Quita `&& i != 3` y funcionará.

Comment: muchas gracias @Trauma ya me funciono <3

Answer (score 1):

En los if siempre se usa el doble igual:

```
int leer(int a[]);

int main() {

    int vec[10]={3,3,3,3,5,5,9,9,9,9};



    printf("Existen %i elementos del numero 3",leer(vec));
    return 0;
}
int leer(int a[]){

    int j;

    j=0;

    for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++){
        if(a[i]==3){
            j =j+1;
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```